# Howto export/import Magento reviews

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, export-to-csv

Due to all kind of upgrade-problems I want to export my 1.4.2 Magento webstore to version 1.7.0.2
I succesfully did an export/import with all my products but I also want to export/import my 140 reviews for several products. Is this possible and if so how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free extension, "Product Review import/export", using dataflow profiles:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-import-export.html

It's quite slow (surprise, surprise), but for 140 reviews that should not be a problem. Also I'd advise to delete the extension immediately after the import is done because it contains a potential security hole due to plain SQL queries with unescaped data.